# How to encrypt data on my website before sending to server-side or client side?

Tags: php, ajax, security, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption

First of all, I have an SSL certificate but when making a post request using ajax it is possible to manipulate data using some tools. Is there any way to use a private key and public key to encrypt my data. I know we have to use the public key at the client-side and the server will decrypt using a private key but don't know how to use them. At the server-side I have PHP & I am sending POST request using AJAX and there is no database, I just want to secure data moving between client and server.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: if you are using `https`, do you really the complexity and extra processing for this ?  the pipe between the cliend and server is already encrypting the data for you.

Comment: even after using https data can be manipulated by some tools @YvesLeBorg

Comment: What tools do you mean? And what manipulation do you mean? Yes, you can see the network traffic, domain, etc. but data is encrypted via https. ssl gives you 3 things: encryption - so prevents reading, data integrity - so prevents manipulation and authentication.

Comment: SSL protects data from man-in-the-middle interception and manipulation. Including XmlHttpRequests (ajax). So the data in the packets between client and server are encrypted. It does not prevent reading data directly on the server or already received by the client (IE: spyware). If you are concerned about protecting the data received by the client as well, I suggest [JWT](https://jwt.io/), which allows for a public/private key based data transmission.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to define the exact threat so that you can mitigate it.

One typical threat is a man-in-the-middle (3rd party) captures and reads or modifies application traffic. This is mitigated by TLS (https), you usually don't need any more protection beyond always using https for communications.

What I think you had in mind though is a legitimate user modifying his own requests and responses. What you need to acknowledge is this will always be possible and easy. A user can send any request to your app from any client, which will be indistinguishable from requests made by your own unmodified client. That's how http works. Also whatever you put in your client (a key for example) will also be available to your user and can be used in another client. You cannot securely prevent decompilation and extraction of any data (see how software piracy is still a thing). You also cannot prevent a user from proxying traffic through his own trusted tools to observe and modify it.

What you can and have to do is implement secure funcionality on the server side. Always authenticate and authorize requests, and never trust anything that comes from a client. It's too broad for a simple answer how to actually achieve this.